# stepping into application.run(...) doesn't show code to step through

Tags: excel, vba

I want to share an experience here so you don't spend too much time...
I use Excel within Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

I have an Excel file file**A**.xlsb which does

- open file**B**.xlsb from a source folder
- modify something in file**B**
- save file**B**.xlsb to another folder (target folder)
- call function **funcB** in file**B**.xlsb with Application.Run "'" & file**B**name & "'" & "!**funcB**", [parameter...]
- save & close file**B**.xlsb

  ```
              Set appO = Application()
              udfTmp = appO.Run("'" & strFullTgtFilename & "'" & "!reCalc_npFB", _
                                  dummyColl, _
                                  colVarsAv_dtMtrx_TotEff, _
                                  colVarsAv_dtMtrx_iFlag, _
                                  PPlistsSheetName, _
                                  LRC_logFilename, _
                                  algID, _
                                  varErrMsg)
  ```

When I step through the code in file**A** everything's fine until Application.Run...
Pressing F8 doesn't show the code in file**B**/**funcB** but keeps the Application.Run statement highlighted. I can keep on pressing F8 or press F5 until funcB ended and stepping through file**A** continues as usual. And: **funcB** is executed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a good number of hours I found a solution (or rather a workaround):
I changed the code in fileA:

- open file**B**.xlsb from the source folder
- modify something in file**B**
- save file**B**.xlsb to another folder (target folder)
- **close fileB.xlsb**
- **re-open fileB.xlsb from it's target (!) folder**
- call Application.Run "'" & file**B**name & "'" & "!func**B**",

  => stepping in with F8 works nicely as expected
- save & close file**B**.xlsb